# Getting invalid_argument error in Firestore Database Rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have set the following rule in my Firestore Database rules.

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    function getUser(userId) {
        let user = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId));
      return user;
    }
    
    function getRole(userId) {
        let roleId = getUser(userId).data.role;
        let role = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/roles/$(roleId)).data; // ERROR
      return role;
    }
  
    function isPermitted(entity_action, userId) {
        return getRole(userId)[entity_action];
    }
  
    match /action_items/{action_item_id} {
      allow get, list, read: if request.auth != null && isPermitted("action_item.read", request.auth.uid);
    }
  }
}
```

But get the following error on simulation.

> Error running simulation — Error: simulator.rules line [12], column [17]. Function not found error: Name: [get].;
>
> Error: Invalid argument provided to call. Function: [get], Argument: ["||invalid_argument||"]

Any idea how I can resolve this error that I'm getting? Attaching a screenshot of the console.
[image: Firebase Console Error Screenshot]

[image]

Comment: It could be that it doesn't like the ".data" part at the end, judging from line 6 the "get" function should be fine. What happens if you remove .data?

Comment: @Echizzle - Still the same error - https://imgur.com/a/DlSbLAr

Comment: Is the role data structured the exact same way as "users"? From the message the problem is coming from the argument passed into get.

Comment: `role` in `users` is a `string` attribute - https://imgur.com/a/lt8L7Rf
I even tried changing the type to `reference` but that didn't change anything.

Comment: I had some issues with simulator in Firebase console. If updating the values as in my answer don't work there, do try querying directly from Firebase SDK once. They did work on local Firestore emulator (and failed when using `roles/admin` as value). On a note `return getRole(userId)[entity_action];` will look for a field with name `action_item.read` and not a map `action_item` with property `read`. Refer to the attached screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be value of `role` in user document. It's value `roles/admin` which is not a [valid document ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#document_ids). That essentially like fetching a document with `roles/roles/admin` that looks a bit like path to a collection.

Try changing the value of role in user's document to just `admin` and also document ID in `roles` collection should be `admin`.

Users collection:

[image]

Roles collection:

[image]